# LESS mix variable into attribute name in an attribute selector expression

Tags: css, less

How can I implement the following syntax correctly?

```
.jacket(@classname, @attrname, @value) {
    .class-prefix-@{classname}[some-prefix-@{attrname}~="@{value}"] {
        //                                 ^Error From Here
        // Attributes
    }
}
```

lessc shows that there is an `SyntaxError: expected ']' got '@'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a bug actually, this workaround should do the trick:

```
.jacket(@classname, @attrname, @value) {
    @attr: ~'some-prefix-@{attrname}';
    .class-prefix-@{classname}[@{attr}~="@{value}"] {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar problem, but the error is `Expected ']' but found '{'` (rather than `@` in the above). I've tried this workaround, but I'm getting the same problem with the `{` in the writing of `attr` (in the string `[@{attr}...`).

Comment: I've tried without the `{`s and now it's saying `Expected ']' but found 'd'`, so maybe the problem _is_ with the `@`, and the error is just wrong. Still not getting the workaround to do it for me, though :(