# Less Mixin using variable in attribute selector

Tags: css, less, mixins

EDIT: The issue might be with a bug in dotless, which is what we're using.

I'm trying to write a Less Mixin method for writing out a lot of CSS styles. The general format of the method is:

```
.icon-styles(@name) {

    .@{name}-icon {
        background-image: url('../images/icon-@{name}.png');
        display: none;
    }

    [data-@{name}="true"] .@{name}-icon {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Such that the icon is only visible if a containing object has the related attribute set.

However, I'm getting an error at the attribute selector saying:

```
Expected ']' but found '{'
```

Pointing to the `@` inside the square brackets.

I've found this post:

[LESS mix variable into attribute name in an attribute selector expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674761/less-mix-variable-into-attribute-name-in-an-attribute-selector-expression/18675264#comment33922889_18675264)

With a similar issue, and the answer suggests it might be a bug, but unfortunately the workaround doesn't work for me. I'm getting the same error on trying to write out `attr` inside the brackets.

I've also tried writing it like this:

```
[~'data-@{name}'="true"] .@{name}-icon {
```

Which gets rid of the error, but then @{name} is not resolved in the resulting css.

Does anyone know if there's any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is the same as suggested in [LESS mix variable into attribute name in an attribute selector expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674761/less-mix-variable-into-attribute-name-in-an-attribute-selector-expression/18675264#comment33922889_18675264). You're just missing the main point of it: "concatenation of interpolated variables is not supported inside `[attr]` blocks", so you need to move out of it:

```
.icon-styles(@name) {

    .@{name}-icon {
        background-image: url('../images/icon-@{name}.png');
        display: none;
    }

    @data-name: ~'data-@{name}';
    [@{data-name}="true"] .@{name}-icon {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I've tried. Tried it again now, just cut-n-pasting from your answer, and I still get: `Expected ']' but found '{'`...

Comment: I've also tried (just to see what would happen): `[icon-name=@{name}]` and I get the same error.

Comment: @SvendHansen: It must be your specific LESS processor you are using, as the above code works at [less2css.org](http://less2css.org/) back to version 1.4.

Comment: Seems we're using dotless, so maybe that's the issue. Cheers :)

Comment: @Svend Hansen Yep, dotless implements quite ancient Less version (~1.3.3) and there you need to use old selector interpolation syntax (e.g. `(~"@{var}")`) instead of normal `@{var}` (But interpolation inside attribute selectors may be not supported at all there, I do not remember for sure, sorry).